# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. > A failure occurred while executing

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication

When I am trying to google auth to my app. this error occured.Could anyone explain

this is buildgradle inside android => app => gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this is android => drc => build.gradele

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.cake"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    //implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.2.1')
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.0')
    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

}
```

I got error like this

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules jetified-guava-20.0 (com.google.guava:guava:20.0) and jetified-listenablefuture-1.0 (com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0)

```
 Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 30s

when I user fluttert run --verbose

```
] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +3 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
[   +1 ms] > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
[        ]    > Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules jetified-guava-20.0 (com.google.guava:guava:20.0) and jetified-listenablefuture-1.0
(com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0)
[        ]      Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[        ] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 33s
[ +466 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 34.2s)
[   +5 ms] Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
[   +3 ms] "flutter run" took 35,384ms.
[   +6 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:669:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1125:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:92:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: try flutter run --verbose and show some of the logs

Comment: you can check it

Comment: Can you tell me your flutter version

Comment: Flutter 2.5.0-5.0.pre

Comment: I think you have added this line apply plugin: 'com.android.application' twice

Comment: but  I removed one but same error occured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-android' to your bulid.gradle:app. refer this and this for more info.
sure  its work

```
 implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-android'
```

Answer (score 0):

check your dependency in pusbpec.yaml file.
this error made because you add one dependency two time or more than one in pusbpec.yamel file